# Paid Social Traffic Channel Is Not Showing on GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am getting trouble in GA4 after migration. I have been running Facebook ads, and Google ads for my website but Paid social traffic is not showing on GA4. GA4 is recording the overwhelming majority of my traffic as organic social, not paid social. I have added UTM tagging but all are showing it in the Organic social channel. I want the paid social traffic from other channels. I do not know why is it not showing on GA4.

How do I differentiate organic social and paid social traffic? I have attached a screenshot for your ref.

Can anybody please guide me on how I differentiate social organic traffic and paid traffic?

[image]